# quickblox response returning access denied when deleting custom object records

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

I am trying to simply delete a record from a custom objects class like so.

```
[QBCustomObjects deleteObjectWithID:deletingID className:className delegate:self];
```

The server responds with this.

> DELETE http://api.quickblox.com/data/Appointments/520bdd08535c12410901514a.xml

headers:{

```
"QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.7";

"Qb-Token" = 906a5cbc316a904b08bcb9dc8a9a84c0d2e04eab;

"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
```

}

parameters:

raw body:

2013-08-26 14:02:05.135 ClientScheduler[32062:110b] Request finished, response:

RestResponse:

---

headers:{

```
"Cache-Control" = "no-store";

Connection = close;

"Content-Language" = en;

"Content-Length" = 228;

"Content-Type" = "text/html";

Date = "Mon, 26 Aug 2013 21:25:44 GMT";

Server = PWA;
```

}

body:Access Denied

You are not allowed to access the document.

I have confirmed that the logged in user does have delete access for the record in the access control list. The weird thing is sometimes the delete will work and sometimes it won't.

```
- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
  if([result isKindOfClass:QBCOCustomObjectResult.class]){
      if(result.success){
          //handle call back
      }
  }
}
```

The result.success is showing true, even though the server response is saying otherwise. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is kind of firewall in your local network which blocks request

There is a header

```
Server = PWA;
```

QuickBlox doesn't return PWA header, it returns something like **nginx/...**